# How to copy a Object<T> to an array

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public int FruitID { get; set; }
    public string FruitTitle { get; set; }
    public string FruitName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to get all FruitTitles within a `string[]`.

I have an object `List<Fruit>`

Comment: What do you have to begin with ? a `List<Fruit>` ?

Comment: can make it more clear?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What problems are you having copying the data yourself?

Comment: @Servy I was trying this, int index = list.FindIndex(f => f.Bar == 17); , but it wasn't working, enough for you now ???

Comment: @CustomizedName No, not in the least.  How is that even slightly related to this?  Your class doesn't even *have* a `Bar` memeber, there's no reason to find the item where a given value is 17 to copy all of the items over, there is no new structure.  It looks like you just copied a single random line of code from some entirely unrelated section and claimed it as your attempt at solving this problem.  It's not.

Comment: @Servy what I am trying to do is to find out, if a string[] contains a string or not, so I tried using FindIndex method but it didn't worked, above is just an example...

Comment: @CustomizedName That's an *entirely* different problem than what you've described in your question.  Finding out if any of the items in the list has a title of a set value shouldn't involve copying all of the values to an array.

Comment: @Servy, oh, You know I am new to C#, is there any better way of doing it please tell me

Comment: Start out by fixing the question to ask how to do what you actually want to do, rather than something entirely different, and while you're at it, include the code that you were using to solve that problem, and explain why it isn't working.  Does it not compile, does it throw an exception, does it produce the wrong value, etc.

Comment: @Servy ok going to ask another question, don't want to piss off take people who already answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string[] fruitTitles = fruits.Select(fruit => fruit.FruitTitle)
                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: It's the very first right answer. But the string[] bleeds my eyes now I am so used with the implicit "var" declaration.

Comment: @Larry Lol, sometimes it's better to make it explicit. The sample above may not be the best example, but can you tell the type of `x` by looking at this code: `var x = GetData()`?

Comment: @dcastro you are 100% right.

Comment: +1, I also like to use explicit code like dcastro said :)

Comment: Someone is having a bad day, probably.

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote, Not really sure why this answer is downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an list, try this:

Add the namespace:

```
using System.Linq;
```

try using the `Select` method:

```
string[] FruitTitles = list.Select(x => x.FruitTitle).ToArray();
string[] FruitNames = list.Select(x => x.FruitName).ToArray();
```

You also could create an anonmymous object to get both strings, for sample:

```
string[] titleNames = list.Select(x => new { x.FruitTitle, x.FruitName })
                          .ToArray();
```

More tips about [linq](/questions/tagged/linq): http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Downvote needs a comment, It should be required in Stack Overflow :/

Answer (score 1):

```
var fruitTitles = fruits.Select(f => f.FruitTitle).ToArray();
```

By the way, you can use `var` instead of `string[]`: this is [implicit declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx): fruitTitle will automatically be recognized as a string array.

Comment: Thanks for having edited the code formatting, Sir !

Answer (score 1):

use `Linq Select` Operator it will project all `FruitTitle` into an array

```
    List<Fruit> fruits = new List<Fruit>();
    var allFruitTitles fruits.Select(f => f.FruitTitle).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list with Fruit, then you will get a list of FruitTitles by this.

```
var list = List<Fruit>();
string[] tmp = new string[list.Count];
for(int i=0;i<list.Count;i++)
{
    tmp[i] = list.ElementAt(i).FruitTitle;
}
```